# visual studio cordova, uncaught typeError, cannot read property of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am creating an Android APP with visual studio and Cordova.
i added the plugin for netword information
[image]
and added the code from the documentation i found here:https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/
[image]
but when i run the project, it return an error of undefined
what else can i do?

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduced the problem. Could you please try it in an empty blank project?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the checkConnection function in the index.html, add it to the index.js, inside of the onDeviceReady.

```
    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
         checkConnection();
    };

function checkConnection(){
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

    alert(states[networkState]);

}
```

That should work.